# Empty DataGrid when binding a List

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I'm trying to bind a list of class A:

```
class ClassA
{
    public int Number;
    public int[,] AnArray;
}
```

To my DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="ResultsDataGrid" DataContext="{Binding ResultsForGrid}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ResultsForGrid}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,10,176,0" Height="220.378" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number"  Binding="{Binding Path=Number}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Array Rows"  Binding="{Binding Path=AnArray.GetLength(0)}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Array Columns"  Binding="{Binding Path=AnArray.GetLength(1)}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

To bind it I'm using a `List<ClassA> ResultsForGrid;` which contains all the elements I'll ever want to show in the view and is declared as a global variable in my window class. When my list is filled with all the elements of ClassA I need to display I set the ItemsSource like

```
ResultsDataGrid.ItemsSource = ResultsForGrid;
```

The odd thing is that when I run the code I get a dataGrid with the correct headers and correct number of rows (number of elements in ResultsForGrid) but completely empty.

I've tried many combinations of Bindings and DataContext since this view seems to be prone to get questions on the web but all to no avail.

Comment: there are mupltiple problems with your bindings. MSDN Bindings Declarations article should help you to fix them: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300(v=vs.100).aspx#Path_Syntax

Comment: Either don't set DataContext over DataGrid or Change Binding of DataGrid  like this ItemsSource="{Binding}".. Might be this will solve your problem..

Comment: have you tried changing to jagged array

Comment: @Neil I'm just curious, how would a jagged array help me?

Comment: @MJGalram Dont know why i sense some sarcasm as if it was a stupid statement but have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays

Comment: @Neil I did think it could be read sarcastically but I really didn't know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your

```
class ClassA
{
    public int Number;
    public int[,] AnArray;
}
```

should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and fields should be replaced by properties:

```
private _number;
public int Number
{
    get { return _number; }
    set
    {
        _number= value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

You can't use methods in XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Array Rows"  Binding="{Binding Path=AnArray.GetLength(0)}"/>
```

Create property that wraps this `AnArray.GetLength(0)` and bind to that property.

You also need class that wraps `List<ClassA>` and the instance of that class should be `DataContext` of your `DataGrid` instance.

Comment: Ok, I can now get some text in my Grid. All I did was change the class to contain properties. I didn't add the `INotifyPropertyChanged` since I want the grid to be constant. I didn't need to wrap my list or anything else.

Comment: You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged to update your class instance from edition through data grid.
Don't forget to add UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged in your xaml too.